# Sharepoint 2012 Authentication for non-AD users

Tags: authentication, sharepoint-2010, active-directory, single-sign-on

We have a sharepoint site that is used both internally and externally.  Internal users are authentication via AD and there are no issues.  The external users are authenticated using STS and the Portal User Table.  However whenever an external user tries to open a document they have to re-enter their login credentials.

This happens everytime they open a document unless they happen to have left the application that the document is read in is left open, i.e. if they open a word document, leave it open and then open another word document then they don't get asked for credentials.

This is obviously a royal pain as we are using the site for document review, revision and collaboration.  Our systems team say this is working as designed and there is nothing that can be done about it.  Is there any practical way to resolve this without the external users having to specifically configure something on their own system or network?

Thanks

Jim

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found quite some time ago..

1. In Internet Explorer, click on Tools and select **Manage add-ons**
2. Highlight **Toolbars and Extensions** in left navigation.
3. Locate **SharePoint OpenDocuments Class**
4. Right-click and click the **Disable** button
5. Close and refresh browser